# ¿Cómo puedo cargar una ventana modal con datos de una consulta?

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, pdo, bootstrap-5

tengo un problema que no se por donde empezar; les cuento tengo un formulario con datos de una consulta realizada a mysql, uso php para programar.

Los resultados de la consulta se muestran en una tabla y se muestran bien, le añadí un botón a cada resultado con el objetivo de mostrar en una ventana modal información extraída de la base de datos, con el nombre que se muestra en la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, lo que quiero hacer es mostrar en una ventana modal todas las prescripciones que ha hecho el representante; ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

uso Bootstrap, php, mysql

Comment: en el evento onclik mandas el id del representante, haces un apeticion con ajax y haces la consulta que quieras para mostrar en pantalla

Comment: Necesitas para hacer eso Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript. Puedes incluso prescindir del modal, y mostrar los nuevos datos que traigas del servidor de forma dinámica debajo de cada fila por ejemplo... aunque depende del contexto, muchas veces esto es mejor desde el punto de vista de UX, que estar abriendo modales, que, al fin y al cabo, son una ventana adicional. Con Ajax o Fetch tú puedes concebir la página actual como un escritorio de trabajo donde vas cargando/mostrando/ocultando elementos de forma dinámica sin moverte de la página.

Comment: Gracias por sus comentarios, he estado averiguando con respecto a AJAX la verdad soy nuevo en ese tema; me parece interesante lo de la API Fetch; en especial por lo de la UX. gracias. Si tiene un enlace donde pueda aprender de mejorar manera AJAX se los agradezco

Comment: Si, ajax es muy usado para realizar paginas SPA como react y angular

Comment: Fetch, por decirlo de algún modo, es Ajax mejorado, simplificado y modernizado. Si optas por Fetch, [aquí tienes un punto de partida](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), y si te decides por Ajax, lo que suelen pulular son ejemplos basados en el Ajax de jQuery, que no tiene por qué ser el mejor (jQuery es un sucedáneo y [*Es posible que no necesites jQuery*](https://youmightnotneedjquery.com/)), simplemente se ha expandido por facilidad y por otros motivos que no vienen al caso ahora.

Comment: Gracias tenia inconvenientes con Jquery porque bootstrap 5, ya no incluye jquery y me estaba confundiendo. gracias por el apoyo :D